# Check json url works file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, error-handling

Hi right now I know that sometimes the JSON script doesn't work. I just want to do a thing to try it and if it doesn't work to try something else without the error. This works but I don't like this way to fix errors.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

The code right now is:

```
try{
    $json_file = file_get_contents(XXX);
    if(!$json_file){
        return "error";
    }else{
        $list = json_decode($json_file, true);
        return $list;
    }
}catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

The warning I get is:

> Warning: file_get_contents(XXX):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
>   HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST in 
>   C:\wamp\www\mvc\app\models\accounts_model.php on line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function

```
<?php
function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

$fileContents = file_get_contents($filename);

if(isJson($fileContents)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: still get this Warning: file_get_contents

Comment: What's the file url or file path you trying to fetch ?

Comment: it dont change anything if u know the url you can write a failed url and do that code and u get the same result

Comment: i dont wanna stop error reporting cuz error reporting only helps i just wanna have a code that try if content is okay and if content is okay do the content translation and then decode it

Comment: error_reporting(0); is the same as php.ini:s error reporting